# How to run function objects(Maya, Python)?

Tags: python-2.7, function, maya

Sometimes when I query a command of a button or something like that I get this:

For example:

```
cmds.menuItem('MtoAReleaseNotes', query = True, command = True)

>>> <function <lambda> at 0x0000019849774588>
```

So how do I run these commands via Python?

Comment: I updated my answer below. If you want to edit or analyze the ArnoldMenu, did you already check the arnoldmenu.py file in MtoA's scripts/mtoa/ui directory?

Comment: Deleting the old code is confusing if the answers are related to the orginal code. Well... exactly as described in the answer below. Simply put the result of your cmds.menuItem(x, query = True, command = True) into a variable and execute it with variableName()  Did you try it? Show us the code of what you have done.

Comment: So you do not have an idea how to put the result of the query into a variable like this: f = cmds.menuItem('MtoAReleaseNotes', query = True, command = True) ?? And then do f()? Did you read my answer below? That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: I understood you answer and it works great, that is why I accepted your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<function callback at 0x0000021B812B24A8>
```

Is a function object like this one:

```
def hello():
    print "Hello"

f = hello
```

Now f contains the function object for hello:

```
<function hello at 0x0000019493BCE7B8>
```

And it can be executed by using "()" so try this:

```
f()
```

The result should be "Hello". Corresponding to your updated question this should work:

```
f = cmds.menuItem(x, query = True, command = True)
```

and to run the command:

```
f()
```

Comment: But can I run the commands with ONLY having the <function callback at 0x0000021B812B24A8>

or

lambda <function <lambda> at 0x0000021B8696C5F8>?

Comment: Yes, e.g. you have requested a callback like this f=cmds.button(name, query=True, c=True) - not completely sure about the exact button syntax - then execute it with f().

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem, the ONLY thing I have is '<function callback at 0x0000021B812B24A8>' or 'lambda <function <lambda> at 0x0000021B8696C5F8>', nothing more, no button, nothing else.
Can I somehow run the corresponding function?

Comment: Where do you get these function objects from? Can you show us some code, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @Lala_Ghost In your query, you're asking for the command/function that gets executed when the menu item is called. What you got back is exactly what you asked for; the function to be executed. haggi krey's answer is accurate. You won't get any button because a button is a different UI element, it is not part of a menuItem (regardless of what you see as a user in Maya). MenuItems are their own UI objects and have commands (functions/actions) also associated to them. That being said, a menuItem and button can use the same command function.